# Corrupted input stream from class loader

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, resources, birt

I have a following problem and I am wondering where could be the cause. I am trying to load resources form `conf`folder of the `JBoss` server.

```
final String REPORT_DESIGN = "report_name.rptdesign"; //xml file
templateIS = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(REPORT_DESIGN);
```

this works fine, I am even able to write the stream into the text file and I get correct result. But problem is when I am trying to pass the input stream to the [Birt](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) engine, I always get `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: The design file <stream> has error and can not be run` .

I've tried also the version with `/`beginning of the file.

When I tried to load the same file from resources of my project (so from the jar file with `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream`), it worked. Also I am reading property file from the same `JBoss` folder in the same way and it works too. I am really stucked on this one, what could possible cause such strange error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a `null` check to make sure you can actually find the resource (ie. `Validate.notNull(templateIS, "%s not found in classpath", REPORT_DESIGN)` or similar). That will make sure that you can actually find the report.
2. Check whether you have umlauts (characters with code point > 128) in your BIRT report. If you have, then make sure the encoding of the report is correct and that the file is actually in that encoding.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I realized where was the problem, I had a malformed XML file there, so it was my fault.